# Insert row into table with only one column, primary key and identity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert

Here is a table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableOnlyPK
(
    Id tinyint PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1)
)
```

Now I need to insert row into that table through T-SQL statements: I've tried few solutions, but no one worked.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableOnlyPK () VALUES ()  -- not worked
```

Comment: Is there any construction that will force SQL to alone write new PK into table. I know that it is feasible with IDENTITY_INSERT, but I am wondered  if it is possible without that statement.

Comment: You should indicate columns names and/or values and besides you should know that the pk column should be ignored if it is an identity field

Comment: If a column is IDENTITY, then you cannot insert user value in that column (without IDENTITY_INSERT)

Comment: No you can't .BTW what's the use of this table ?

Comment: The question is why would you want a table like that in the first place

Comment: @Zohar - This can have numerous usages.  One might be as a general sequence / latest ID across an entire application.

Comment: as of sql server 2012 there is a [sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) object. I guess it might be useful if you are using an older version. This is what I mean by asking why. if the OP is using 2012 or higher, he might be better of with a sequence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableOnlyPK DEFAULT VALUES
```

You have created below table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableOnlyPK
(
    Id tinyint PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1)
)
```

Each time you fire : `INSERT INTO dbo.TableOnlyPK DEFAULT VALUES`, you will insert one row in IDENTITY column.

So if you execute:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableOnlyPK DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO dbo.TableOnlyPK DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO dbo.TableOnlyPK DEFAULT VALUES
```

It will result:

[image]

Comment: Bravo! That is what I need

Answer (score 3):

To insert an "empty" record, you can use `DEFAULT VALUES` where the columns will use any defined `DEFAULT`, or, in this case the `IDENTITY`

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableOnlyPK]
DEFAULT VALUES
```

Comment: Bravo! That is what I need